# How to scrape img src into GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I know the method to extract any text from the page into GTM using DOM element. However, how can we pull img src (attribute) value onto GTM using DOM element?

```
<div class="original">
<img itemprop="image" ng-src="https://www.123456.com/img/uploads/1/265/545265.jpg?type=product" src="https://www.123456.com/img/uploads/1/265/545265.jpg?type=product">
</div>
```

I'm trying div.original img, but it doesn't work.[GTM example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWd5p.jpg).

Expected result: The image src value must be extracted into GTM. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `src` as the Attribute Name? Something like:

```
Selection Method: CSS Selector
Element Selector: "div.original img"
Attribute Name: "src"
```